# Can't access database server over VPN

Tags: vpn, mac-osx, oracle

I am attempting to connect to an Oracle server via a VPN.  I have tried to do so, unsuccessfully, from OSX and, alternately, from a Windows XP VM machine (VMWare Fusion) running on OSX.

I can, however, connect to my Workstation (that is on the LAN) over a VPN using OSX and the Windows VM.

Is there anything that I can do to get remote access to the Oracle server?

Here's a summary of the environment:

Server

- on LAN
- Oracle database

Workstation

- on LAN
- Windows XP
- can ping Server by name or IP

OSX Client

- connected to LAN over VPN using the Apani/Nortel VPN client (I think.  I run 'cvc' from within Terminal)
- can ping Workstation by fully-qualified name (NetBIOS name + domain) or IP
- can NOT ping server by name or IP, however name can be resolved to an IP address

VM Client

- sharing host's (OSX) network connection using NAT
- Windows XP
- connect to LAN over VPN using Nortel VPN client for Windows
- can ping Workstation by fully-qualified name (NetBIOS name + domain) or IP
- can NOT ping server by name or IP, however name can be resolved to an IP address

EDIT

I was informed:

"Since your VPN account is set up to only access the subnet where your laptop is, you won't be able to directly access anything else.".

Is there a way to by-pass this limitation?

Comment: can anyone else get to the db server over the VPN? It's possible that VPN connections are on a different subnet and cross-routing is not enabled / has been disabled

Comment: I haven't attempted to do so, but I would be that I would be able to take the Workstation home (it's a laptop), connect to the VPN, and access the Server.

Assuming that my assertion is correct, does that change your opinion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Warren's comment was correct.  The system's administrator said "Since your VPN account is set up to only access the subnet where your laptop is, you won't be able to directly access anything else.".

Answer (score 0):

My guess is going to be that your Window VM is resolving the server name using NetBIOS or some similar non-DNS related way.

Regarding your edit, only being able to connect to the subnet where your workstation is (I assume you meant workstation, rather than laptop, unless your laptop is your workstation), you could remote desktop into the laptop and work like that, or you could ask the network/VPN administrator to create you an IPSec tunnel to the network with the server, then alter your Nortel VPN client's configuration to speak to that tunnel as well.